# CSS for specific WooCommerce product

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a stupid CSS issue, that is probably something extremely simple. I'll preface by saying I've cleared the cache, loaded in different browsers, and all that jazz.

So I want to use CSS to hide a few elements on a couple specific products (price, add to cart, etc) because it's easier than removing with PHP (or so I thought). So I found the `postid` for the first product, got the classes, edited the page with the chrome inspector to make sure I had the CSS correct. Then copy and pasted into the custom CSS. Here is my code:

```
.postid-260 .woocommerce div.product p.price {
display: none;
}
```

That didn't work, so I looked in the body tag to see if maybe I was missing something. Nope, just has postid-260

```
product-template-default single single-product postid-260
```

There's a little more on there but it's irrelevant. Things like admin bar, etc.

I look further and see that there is an ID for product-260. So I put in this code:

```
#product-260 .postid-260 .woocommerce div.product p.price {
    display: none;
}
```

Nothing, so I try it as just this:

```
#product-260 .woocommerce div.product p.price {
    display: none;
}
```

Still not making the change. If I do it without trying to target the specific product or post, it works just fine. Only problem is it removes the price from all the products. Every time I tried a different CSS I hard-reloaded, cleared cache, tried in different browsers, etc. So is there something I'm missing?

Comment: With a link to the live site we could take a look at the CSS and see for sure, but it's likely a matter of a rule with higher specificity. There are a lot of resources on working out the ranking of various combinations of CSS selectors, but often when working within the constraints of a framework or pre-built system you have to hold your nose and reach for the `!important` annotation. See more on specificity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I would include a link, however I'm building it locally so I could post screen shots, but that'd be about it. I'll give the !important a shot